# How to create a list of checkbox where at least 1 box is active

Tags: javascript, checkbox, knockout.js

I have an example that contains 2 checkbox. I would like to make sure that there is always 1 checkbox is active, it means either checkbox 1 or checkbox 2 or both of them can be active. How can I do that?

```js
function DemoItem(id, name) {
    var self = this;

    self.id = ko.observable(id);
    self.Name = ko.observable(name);
    self.Selected = ko.observable(false);
}

function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.availableItems = ko.observableArray();
    self.associatedItemIds = ko.observableArray();

    self.init = function () {
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(1, 'One'));
        self.availableItems.push(new DemoItem(2, 'Two'));
       
    };
    
    self.toggleAssociation = function (item) {
        if (item.Selected() === true) console.log("dissociate item " + item.id());
        else console.log("associate item " + item.id());
        item.Selected(!(item.Selected()));
        return true;
    };
}

var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
viewModel.init();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Available Items:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.availableItems">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="value: id(), checked: $root.associatedItemIds, click: $root.toggleAssociation" /> 
    <span data-bind="text: '&nbsp;' + Name()"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
<br/>
Associated Item Ids:
<div data-bind="foreach: $root.associatedItemIds">
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In `self.toggleAssociation` whenever you uncheck something you first count how many `item`s are checked by looping through `self.availableItems` and counting those for which `item.Selected() === true`. If there's only one then you *don't* uncheck it.

```
self.toggleAssociation = function (item) {
    if (item.Selected() === true) {
        var howManyAreSelected = 0;

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.availableItems(), function (item) {
            if (item.Selected() === true) {
                howManyAreSelected += 1;
            }
        });

        if (howManyAreSelected > 1) {
            item.Selected(false);
        }
    }
    else {
        item.Selected(true);
    }
    return true;
};
```